# screen and $TERM and misformatted vi

Tags: linux, terminal, vim, vi, stty

I'm ssh'ing from my Mac (Terminal.app) into a Linux box, where I need to run ckermit or screen over USB to have a console on a second Linux box. (There are no graphics on the second box, and I'm attempting to fix the network configuration.)

This works, but somewhere in between information about terminal size and and some other things get lost, so I cannot really run an interactive editor such as vi on the second Linux box: the display is completely misformatted, making editing impossible. E.g. "vi foo" shows:

```
line 1
      line 2
            line 3
```

Mac and first Linux box have `TERM=vt100`. Second Linux box has `TERM=vt220`. I run screen as `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`. Everything is fine between the Mac and the first Linux box.

`stty -a` are different by default, but in my attempt to make them the same, nothing remarkable happened. Strangest observation: Linux box 1 has `cs8` while Linux box 2 has `cs5` and refuses to change it to `cs8`. (No idea what this means)

I assume this can be made to work somehow, and I'm hoping to learn how.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366423/53656.

Comment: @egmont: Mine seems to be a different problem. I can see the difference with "stty -onlcr" but I have "stty onlcr". The problem also does not occur with just typing commands into the shell, so the CRLF is happening on the command-line, just not inside vi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with some CR-LF related stty setting (there's more of them). You also mentioned you're using screen, make sure to check the stty settings both outside and inside screen.

Comment: @egmont: that could be part of it, but only part, because, for example, the remote editor has a very wrong idea about the screen size. E.g. "more" paginages in strange places.